# ios7 custom interaction with nstextattachment in uilabel

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, nstextattachment

I have an `NSTextAttachment` with an image in a `UILabel` and I would like to perform a custom behaviour when clicking on this attachment.

`UITextViewDelegate` provides an handy method

```
textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:
```

But it can only be used if I'm using `UITextView`.

Is there any solution if Im using `UILabel`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The text attachment becomes part of the model and is treated like a character, so try adding a link to the range of your attachment.
Like this:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:nil];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];

NSAttributedString *imageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableImageString = [imageString mutableCopy];
[mutableImageString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"http://stackoverflow.com" range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableImageString.length)];
```